# Ask vc++ compiler to show compiler warnings when code has explicit casts from char to wchar_t or vice-versa

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, wchar-t

Is there any way for the me to ask the vc++ compiler to show warnings when it encounters an explicit C-style cast in the following cases :

- wchar_t to char and vice-versa
- LPWSTR to LPCSTR and vice-versa

I'm turning on the UNICODE flag while compiling an application using the vc++ compiler and I want to avoid run time errors because of these casts.

Unfortunately the code base is large and I do not want to a manual search for casts and filter them out if they're invalid. I did try searching for documentation on this but nothing useful turned up.

Answer (score 1):

1- Open the project properties and set warning level to 4.
2- casting from wchar_t to char will be warned because you are trying  to cast a large data to small one ( warning 4244 ).
3- casting from char to wchar_t will be warned only if you don't have set unsigned chars on(option /J), In this case char is a signed type and converting it to unsigned will produce warning (warning 4245 ).

Edit: This works for implicit cast. there is no compiler assistance to detect explicit legal casts